# UICollectionView Horizontal Scrolling shows previous items even when paging is enabled

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am implementing a uicollection view with scroll direction set to horizontal. I also enabled the paging option in storyboard. In my view, I can display 4 items at a time. If I have 5 items, the first page has 4 items but the second page has 3 items. Previous items are also displayed on the second page.

I just like to ask how can I prevent this? I want 4 items on first page and only 1 item on the second page. I am thinking of adding items and set them to hidden to do this. Is this the proper way of solving this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? I seem to be having the same issue. I have 4 items total, and each page should contain three items each. The first page gets created properly, but the second page width is evidently only as wide as the 4th item, so it never actually seems to page to the second page... the second "page" contains the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th items and it snaps back. Instead, would have expected it to have only one item on page two. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could set the `contentSize` property of the UICollectionView to the next multiple of its `bounds`?

e.g. for a single-section collection view:

```
NSUInteger itemsPerPage = 4;
NSUInteger pageCount = (NSUInteger) ceilf((float)[collectionView.dataSource numberOfItemsInSection:0] / itemsPerPage);
CGFloat contentWidth = collectionView.bounds.size.width * pageCount;
collectionView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(contentWidth, collectionView.contentSize.height);
```

Comment: At what point should this be done? I tried it in viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear and it didn't work. Just wondering if there was a good place for this.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem, and I solved it in a rather hackish-feeling way, but it works, and I am content with it for now.

Basically what I decided to do was to pad the collection view pages with empty UICollectionViewCells.

I first calculate how many total items there will be. If the total number of items supplied by my NSFetchedResultsController is not an exact multiple of three, then I add the requisite number of items so that the total is a multiple of three.

For example, if I get four categories back, I'll need to add two more to make it a total of six:

```
#define ITEMS_PER_PAGE 3

//...

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSArray *sections = [categoriesFetchedResultsController sections];
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = sections[section];

    NSInteger categoryCount = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    NSInteger extraItemsNeeded = ITEMS_PER_PAGE - (categoryCount % ITEMS_PER_PAGE);
    NSInteger totalItems = categoryCount + extraItemsNeeded;

    NSInteger pages = (NSInteger)(totalItems / ITEMS_PER_PAGE);
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = pages;
    return totalItems;
}
```

Then when it comes time to generate the cells, I do the following:

```
    - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        CategoryCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CategoryCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        // use a generic UICollectionCell for the "empty cell" case.        
        UICollectionViewCell *emptyCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"EmptyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (indexPath.row < [[categoriesFetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count] ) {
            NSManagedObject *object = [categoriesFetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            NSData *imageData = [object valueForKey:@"thumbnail_data"];
            NSString *name = [object valueForKey:@"category_name"];

            cell.image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            cell.label.text = name;
            return cell;
        }

        return emptyCell;
    }
```

I hope this helps someone in the future, since solving this problem was not as straightforward as it should have been, and I was surprised that the flow layout didn't just automatically calculate the pages appropriately.